# Symfony2 with Tinymce and Justboil

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce

I am the beginner in **Symfony**. I am trying to enable **Tinymce** for the textarea. I have installed **stfalcon tinymce bundle**. It works. Then I found the plugin **Justboil** to upload images for the **tinymce**. I have managed to configure it to upload images to the images folder. But when I am uploading images in tinymce they do not appear in the content. Image tag is added, the src points at `/images/name_of_the_image`  but it is not icluded. 
I think the problem is with configuration of uploading in `config.php` of the justboil  .

```
$config['img_path'] = '/images'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

I don't know what should I put here to make it possible for `img src=".............."` to include the image in the content through Tinymce.

Answer (score -1):

Try below configuration regarding image path in your symfony's config.yml
This works for me. I hope it will solve your problem.

```
 stfalcon_tinymce:
        theme:
            advanced:
                relative_urls: false
                remove_script_host: false
                convert_urls: true
                document_base_url: 'http://your.domain.com'
```

Enjoy!